# Squid dstdom_regex issue

Tags: regex, squid

I'm trying to add a regular expression dstdomain in to the CF_Unrest ACL in Squid 3.3.12, as follows:

`acl CF_Unrest dstdom_regex .emlfiles^([0-9])?.com # Dotmailer CDNs`

The aim is to allow domains .emlfiles1.com through .emlfiles9.com

Squid fails to accept the line, claiming it's bungled:

`2015/11/13 12:00:34| aclParseAclLine: ACL 'CF_Unrest' already exists with different type.
FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.conf line 253: acl CF_Unrest dstdom_regex \.emlfiles^([0-9])?\.com # Dotmailer CDNs`

How would I go about achieving what is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not related to regex i think. It is some what related to 'CF_Unrest' acl name.

error

```
ACL 'CF_Unrest' already exists with different type.
```

itself indicate that an ACL with same name(CF_Unrest) is declared above. 
I tried the same config line and squid is starting since there is no conflicting ACL declaration.
Just rename the ACL and try with new name.

Check the ACL declarations in your squid.conf and confirm there is no other acl with name 'CF_Unrest' is declared above this line.

Comment: Yep, this was the answer.

I created a new acl called CF_Unrest_regex and simply added the string 'emlfiles', which works fine rather than trying to be clever and limiting the string to one with numbers on the end...

`acl CF_Unrest_regex dstdom_regex -i emlfiles`